# Jasmine spyOn working where sinon does not?

Tags: coffeescript, jasmine, sinon

Just working on some js testing, and I've been trying to use sinon. I have the following test where I want to stub the draw and draw_association functions. The spyOn from jasmine seems to work, but when I use sinon.spy, it does not. Any ideas as to why?

```
describe "#draw", ->
  text = fixture_text()
  editor = null
  draw_spy = null
  draw_associations_spy = null
  beforeEach ->
    #draw_spy = sinon.spy AwesomeModel.Table.prototype, "draw"
    #draw_associations_spy = sinon.spy AwesomeModel.Table.prototype, "draw_associations"
    spyOn AwesomeModel.Table.prototype, "draw"
    spyOn AwesomeModel.Table.prototype, "draw_associations"
    editor = new AwesomeModel.Editor text
    editor.parse_table_names()

  afterEach ->
    #draw_spy.restore()
    #draw_associations_spy.restore()

  it "unacceptable_coordinates should be the size of the number of tables", ->
    editor.draw()
    expect(editor.unacceptable_coordinates.length).toEqual editor.tables.length
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mis understood what sinon.spy does. It just observes the method, where as jasmine spyOn stubs it out. I switched the above to sinon.stub() instead and it works.